Change color of output from docker compose
I am looking for a way to alter the color of the replies that I get from "docker compose". Everything I have been able to find talks about colorizing the output of logs, I don't believe that is my issue.  I use a black terminal emulator, and parts of the replies to commands are extremely dark blue. To make matters worse, the reverse (e.g. when selected) it is that dark blue background with black text. The only way I can read the output is to copy/paste into a text editor.
The below line in dark says "[+} Running 1/1" and "0.2s".
Is there a configuration file somewhere I'm not finding? Or is there something I can do other than change my own profile's color scheme?


Your question seems to be answered here: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/9818

Yes - THANK YOU!  I searched and could not find anything like that.

Interesting - "NO_COLOR=1" works, but I can't quite figure out how to change the colors.  Plain white text on a black background is perfectly acceptable though.

I generally modify my terminal palette when I encounter this sort of thing (because if I'm seeing it from one application, odds are I'm going to see it from others as well).

Not disagreeing with you larsks - but in this particular case, only the one thing is unreadable.  The output from "docker compose".  If it were more than that, then I would tend to change my profile as well.
